# cmd not showing from spyder script

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I have a python script that I run using spyder. It execute other scripts with os.system("...").
My problem is that the cmd windows are not poping (the code is executed, but I can't monitor it, eg see print() or errors).

it was working before I updated spyder recently.

I tried unchecking the "Hide command line output windows generated by the subprocess module" in Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Advanced settings > Windows adjustments

but nothing changed. How can I changed that?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of spider and python are you using?

Comment: Hi, spyder 4.1.4, with python 3.8.3